# angular build --prod produces styles bundle css file of size 1.4Mb

Tags: angular, sass

I have an angular project and ng build --prod gives me a styles bundle css file of size 1.4MB. Does ng build --prod do a tree shaking on css? I copied scss files from a template project. There are a lot of css not used in my project. Is there a good way to remove unused css? The difficult part is that if you remove some css, you will only notice the error during run time.

Also I do not see a vendor bundle file. where does it go?

Comment: You can check it using `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, in my case it goes to `styles.bunde.js`.

Comment: I installed webpack-bundle-analyzer and checked. vendor js files are bundled within main.bundle.js.

Comment: Usually they are separate, what is your project setup? Using `npm` to manage packages?

Comment: yes, I use npm to manage packages. Is it related? When I do ng build, I see vendor.bundle.js and main.bundle.js. When I do ng build --prod, vendor.bundle.js is not generated. Instead, all the angular lib code are packed in main.bundle.js.